# Target a specific table using CSS3 selector

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Is it possible to use the nth-child selector to target a specific table within it's parent element?

I'm trying to target the 2nd table in a div but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
#div table:nth-child(2) {
    color: blue
}
<div id="div">
    <table>
        <tr>Table 1</tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr>Table 2</tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: You've got invalid HTML, unless that text is (really) wrapped in `<td>` or `<th>` elements the browser will try to fix the invalid HTML by moving the text outside of the `<table>` element.

Answer (score 4):

Your issue could be with the invalid html. You need to wrap the text within `td`.

```
<div id="div">
    <table>
        <tr><td>Table 1</td></tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr><td>Table 2</td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Also make sure you do not have id duplicated.

***[Here's a working CodePen demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/alCus)***

One more thing to be noted is that this will work only if your table is 2nd child of div, if you want to target 2nd table inside its parent you would need to use `nth-of-type(2)`

Answer (score 0):

Problem is your `invalid` HTML

value or item or content should be inside `td`.

```
     <table>
        <tr>
        <td>Table 1</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Z8Q65/)